# Can we do XSLT 2.0 with Netbeans 7?

Tags: xslt, netbeans, netbeans-7, xslt-2.0, jaxp

In its current form, Netbeans only supports XSLT 1.0 and does not support XSLT 2.0.

How do we use XSLT 2.0 with Netbeans 7?

Comment: What library would you use to get XSLT 2.0 support?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen . I don't get your question.. its because i can't find XSLT 2.0 support in netbeans that's why I'm asking if there is one.

Comment: There is an XSLT 1.0 interpreter in the standard Java runtime.  I do not believe there is support for XSLT 2.0 in Java or Netbeans.  Thirdparty implementations like Saxon exist, though.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen . hence this question.. in case someone manages to integrate Netbeans with a Saxon plugin or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to make Saxon the JRE-installation-default XSLT Processor:

(So not only for Netbeans, other Java applications might be impacted as well.)

1. [Get Saxon for Java](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (there are different editions, pick the one suitable for you) and copy saxonXYZ.jar to the jre/lib/ext dir.
2. In the jre/lib dir create a jaxp.properties file with following content:

   javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
3. (Restart Netbeans.) Check success by doing an XSL Transformation: If Saxon has been used the XSLT Processor output will contain "Using net.sf.saxon.Controller XSLT processor from file ..."

[Tested with NetBeans 7.3.1 / Saxon-HE 9.4.0 / JRE 1.7.0_17]

There are other ways of configuring the "TransformerFactory" used in a Java application. See the [JAXP FAQ](https://jaxp.dev.java.net/1.4/JAXP-FAQ.html#pluggability). And of course, there are also other XSLT processors than Saxon that plug into the Java API for XML Processing (JAXP).