# Does JAXP support XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, jaxp

1. My ${java.home} is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51.
2. I extracted saxonHE9-6-0-6J.zip in C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext
3. and add saxonhe9.jar to my classpath variable.
4. Then I created a jaxp.properties file under C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib and add the following lines:

   javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
   javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory","net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl

For testing I use in my stylesheet the following lines

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[@type='Usage']/@name">
  <xsl:value-of select="." separator="', '"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But the output of

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

is a string withoput commas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we do XSLT 2.0 with Netbeans 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315260/can-we-do-xslt-2-0-with-netbeans-7)

Comment: You haven't said whether it worked, or if it didn't, how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want `<xsl:value-of select="//*[@type='Usage']/@name" separator=", "/>` instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[@type='Usage']/@name">
  <xsl:value-of select="." separator="', '"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

as the latter obviously will never output a separator given that you have the `value-of` inside of the `for-each` that ensures that `.` is a single item for the `value-of`.

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKx4 outputs `name 1, name 3` for input sample

```
<root>
    <foo type="Usage" name="name 1"/>
    <foo type="Nonsense" name="name 2"/>
    <foo type="Usage" name="name 3"/>
</root>
```

Comment: '<xsl:value-of select="//*[@type='Usage']/@name" separator=", "/>' shows no output.

Comment: @StellaMaris, consider to edit your question and add minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sry for wasting your time, its working now. I cant explain, what I changed till the beginning of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

JAXP is an interface, not an implementation; and it embraces schema processing and XPath processing as well as XSLT processing.

There are several implementations of the JAXP transformation interface, including the built-in XSLT processor in the JDK, the two versions of Xalan that come in the Xalan-J product from Apache, the Oracle XSLT processor, and Saxon. Of these the only one that supports XSLT 2.0 is Saxon.